# Controller not deallocated when popping it

Tags: ios, memory, uistoryboard

`dealloc` is not called in controller B as it is popped from nav stack.

Ie this (very normal) setup:

Nav controller has controller A as root and a button tap pushes B on top. Then a back button in controller B unwinds to controller A. This is all made through the storyboard interface in IB (I do use a custom segue class that uses no animation on push). Normally (when using xibs only and non-arc) this would eventually call dealloc in controller B as it is popped. But it does not, in my case. Is this normal behaviour of storyboards? Or if not, I made some mistake somewhere, something is hanging onto controller B. FYI I'm using ARC and am not explicitly creating controller B anywhere in code.

It is alarming because I noticed that the constructor of controller B is called with each push of it from A (even after going back from B to A). It would mean the B controllers would leak.

Comment: We can't say without seeing some of your other logic.  Prime candidates are static variables (singleton, etc) and strong reference cycles when using blocks.  Well, to be fair I have never worked with storyboards so maybe it caches them but somehow I doubt it if the constructor is being called every time.

Comment: Have you tried profiling for memory leaks?  - In Xcode Product->Profile (cmd-i) and then select the Leaks instrument.

Comment: Yes, I did and it does not alert a leak when going back and forth between A and B. But as the constructor of B (initWithCoder:) is called for every B, I assume new memory is being allocated with each B, and if dealloc is never called with B that would mean leak... I don't think Instruments catches everything. In these cases, something is holding onto controller B or its view, or something like that. I will try to hunt that down...

Comment: Leaks is largely irrelevant under ARC.  You need to examine the heap directly.  Make sure "record reference count" is on.

Comment: The problem was, as you suggested, a strong reference cycle within a block (I was using a controller within a block deep down in inherited code within a block, and I needed to make a weak version of that before using that in the block). It took a fair amount of step-by-step commenting of lots of pieces of code. I'm just not used to ARC. :-P Well to answer my question, "No it's not normal behaviour of storyboards". Using storyboards would/should not change what's kept in memory or not.